# Set font DPI (font scaling) in Xorg for light Window Managers like Fluxbox

Tags: dpi

When using WMs like Fluxbox there isn't support in the WMs to do font scaling. Font scaling should be set at the Xorg level, but in my experience using xrandr in .xinitrc or .xsession doesn't work in modern Ubuntu versions such as 16.04

Answer (score 1):

**Font Scaling**

As of KDE5 KDE's systemsettings5->Fonts module has a 'Force Fonts DPI' option. This isn't meant to be used unless it has to be, but when used it works well - it scales fonts for all applications, not just KDE ones.

The catch is that it needs to be applied each time you login to Xorg. KDE does this automatically if you set it up through systemsettings5->Fonts. But in non-KDE environments, for example a setup that logs into Kodi direct from SDDM and uses Firefox started from Kodi for Netflix/Youtube, you can set this manually so it's done automatically each time you login to Xorg:
Create ~/.Xresources with contents:

```
Xft.dpi:    144
```

(this file is read by xrdb, and the idea for it came from the systemsettings5->Fonts source code, which is accessible with: apt source plasma-desktop; cd plasma-desktop-*/kcms/fonts/)

Comment: This answer is so underrated, this is the exact thing I was looking for and works in most applications.